# Как установить фоновую картинку для мониторов разного разрешения в библиотеке Pygame (Python)

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

Всем привет, я художник, решил нарисовать игру (платформер), использую библиотеку Pygame. Такой вопрос, как мне нарисовать фоновую картинку для игры, если игра может запускаться на мониторах разного разрешения, в самом Pygame, можно уменьшать и увеличивать изображение, но оно сильно теряет в качестве. В туториалах по Pygame, почему то этот вопрос не рассматривается. Понимаю, мой вопрос наверное супер нубский, но если кто сможет мне объяснить, буду благодарен!

Comment: Нарисовать максимальную картинку под телевизор и дальше только уменьшать ?

Comment: реально? другого варианта нету?

Comment: Незнаю.я предложил 1 вариант при котором не будет ухудшения качества. И всяко проще нарисовать 1 картинку  , чем рисовать 10 под разные мониторы

Comment: и сохранить множество вариантов картинки (уменьшенных в редакторе) для разных моников в папке с игрой? просто сам Pygame уменьшает картинку плохо, она становиться хуже по качеству